# WoW Return to Karazhhan: How do you exit the instance?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

When you are finished with the last boss in **Return to Karazhan** (From *Legion* expansion), you seem to end up in a circular library/planetarium.  It has a twisting passageway onward in the instance, but it doesn't appear to have any way to move backwards in the instance, and no portal back to the entrance.

I even tried dying in the library via long falls.  Took me right back there.  Hotel California?

Is that it? Are you trapped and must hearthstone to get out of the instance?

Or is there a way to either progress back or simply portal to the instance entrance?